# How do I copy symbolic links between servers?

Tags: webserver, symlink, file-transfer

We are moving web servers. (LAMP)

Webserver 1 has hundreds of symbolic links pointing to files in a different directory (eg. ../../files/001.png). When we move over to the new server (have downloaded the site to my computer then reuploading to Webserver 2 using SFTP client Transmit). It does not copy the symbolic links...

Is there a better way to get the symbolic links from one server to another apart from recreating them on the new server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like the following? On Webserver 1:

```
tar czf - the_directory | (ssh Webserver2 "cd /path/to/wherever && tar xzf -")
```

This creates a tar of the stuff to copy to STDOUT, and pipes it to an untar on the other server over ssh. It can be faster than a recursive ssh copy too.

Comment: Any chance I could convince you to further explain what that does and why it should be used :P

Comment: Sure. The point is that tar preserves symbolic links. The above is just a shortcut - you could just tar up + compress the contents of Webserver1, copy it over to Webserver2, then untar it. You may even want to do that so that you have a backup of the pre-migration state. The above avoids the need to write the tar file to disk - instead it just goes straight across the network, and because you're copying a stream of data, instead of individual files, it can be quicker. I used this trick A LOT during a database migration project. Any clearer?

Answer (score 5):

`rsync -a` from one server to another will preserve file attributes and symlinks.

```
rsync -av user@server:/path/to/source user@server2:/path/to/target
```

Comment: Can't use rsync with Webserver 1.

Comment: What system is webserver 1 running? If you have full-ish access to webserver 2, I bet you can still rsync.